# Can I obtain the "native" placeholder color for a text element across browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, placeholder

The context is I need to use select elements built from a framework that I would prefer not to change (respectively jqxComboBox and jqxDropDownList from [jQWidgets](https://www.jqwidgets.com/)), and use their built-in placeholders.

jqxComboBox creates an inner `input` for that with the attribute `placeholder="my text"`, so it gets styled correctly in browser-dependant placeholders gray.

However jqxDropDownList creates an inner `span` with the attribute `unselectable="on"` that by default appears in the page's font color.

I'd like to style the jqxDropDownList accordingly, but the gray changes following the browser. Is there a consistent way to obtain the placeholder color that uses the browser, without having to declare a different rule for every one?

example: this gray is nice for Firefox, but not on Chrome (the difference might seem small here, but it is accentuated with our CSS).

```css
body {
    font-weight: bold;
}

input { /*just for the example*/
    width: 100%;
}
input::placeholder { /*just for the example*/
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

span[unselectable="on"] {
    color: #777777 !important;
}
```

```html
<input style=type="textarea" placeholder="native browser placeholder color"><br>
<span unselectable="on">testing placeholder color emulation</span><br>
<span>what I have currently in my jqxDropDownList</span>
```

**EDIT:** partially solved my problem by overriding placeholders color for all browsers following [this post's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css), but still interested for the sake of pure knowledge..

Answer (score 0):

Try using `color: unset` to use the default color for given element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually it's the contrary: I'd like a regular span to take the color of the placeholders, if I use `unset` it will do what I already have: a black span